# ImportError: cannot import name 'NinjaAPI' from 'ninja'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-ninja

I am working on the Django ninja rest framework. the project is working fine on my machine, but when I try to run it in a virtual environment (venv) and install all requirements.txt including `django-ninja` it raise an error (ImportError: cannot import name 'NinjaAPI' from 'ninja').

The line that causes the error

```py
from ninja import NinjaAPI
```

When I install the ninja, it gives me feedback the package is already installed

```
Requirement already satisfied: django-ninja
```

I use this command to create a virtual env.

```
python3 -m venv venv
```

These are my requirements.txt

```
asgiref==3.4.1
cffi==1.14.6
cryptography==3.4.7
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==3.2.6
django-heroku==0.3.1
django-ninja==0.13.2
gunicorn==20.1.0
jwt==1.2.0
ninja==1.10.2
psycopg2==2.9.1
psycopg2-binary==2.9.1
pycparser==2.20
pydantic==1.8.2
PyJWT==2.1.0
pytz==2021.1
sqlparse==0.4.1
typing-extensions==3.10.0.0
whitenoise==5.3.0
```

Python version

```
Python 3.9.0
```

pip version:

```
pip 21.2.3
```

---

Comment: The steps that I followed to install the project
https://github.com/HusDev/increment_integers_api/tree/master

Answer (score 2):

you need to install only django-ninja (not ninja)

run

```
pip uninstall ninja
```

on your environment, and you should be good to go

Answer (score 0):

This might be specific to Replit, but here's what causes this error for me:

1. I install django-ninja
2. I start setting up my api stuff (everything works)
3. Replit inexplicably installs ninja for some reason
4. I get the error above

To solve it, you'd think that

```
pip uninstall ninja
```

would work. Sometimes it does, sometimes it doesn't. If it doesn't, then you'll need to run

```
pip uninstall django-ninja
pip install django-ninja
```

Why do we need to reinstall django-ninja? I have no idea. Strangely, sometimes after doing all this, I have to uninstall and reinstall django-ninja later in the replit!

To replicate this issue, moving your api.py file from your app to your project will often trigger Replit to install ninja.